Converting an expression into an einsum
I have the following expression that I need to calculate for some matrices:
$$
\sum_{k}c_{t,i,k}\sigma^\prime\left(w_tX_t+b_t\right)_k\left(\sum_\ell w_{t,k,\ell}\tilde{X}_t^{w,\ell}\right)
$$
I could, of course, do this using a for loop, but I'm attempting to use the torch.einsum function to calculate this in a vectorized manner. I'm having trouble understanding how exactly I can combine two summations into a single einsum expression.
For reference:

$c$ is a $n\times m$ matrix
$w$ is a $m\times n$ matrix
$X$ is an $n$-dimensional vector
$b$ is a $m$-dimensional vector
$\tilde{X}$ is a $n\times m \times n$ matrix
The overall output of this should be a $m\times n$ matrix.

Doing each of the sums individually is simple enough. For example, the inner sum (over $\ell$) can be easily written as:
torch.einsum("l..., blmn -> mn", w[k], X_tilde)

However, I can't see a way to combine the double summation into a single einsum expression.
